# Full duplex communication through socket in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Can I use two different threads to read and write from the same socket without any synchronization in java?

My code is -

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Serve s = new Serve();
    }
}
class Serve {

ServerSocket sS;
String serverAddress;
int port;

public Serve() {
    serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    port = 8091;
    try  {
        sS = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server listening on port " + port+ " ...");
        Socket incomming = sS.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to Client.");
        Runnable r = new Read(incomming);
        Runnable w = new Write(incomming);
        Thread read = new Thread(r);
        Thread write = new Thread(w);
        read.start();
        write.start();
        incomming.close();
        sS.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
}
}
class Read implements Runnable {

Socket readSocket;

public Read(Socket readSocket) {
    this.readSocket = readSocket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream inStream = readSocket.getInputStream();
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream)) {
            boolean done = false;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
            while(!done && in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                out.println("Client>" + line);
                if(line.trim().equals("BYE")) done = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}

class Write implements Runnable {

Socket writeSocket;

public Write(Socket writeSocket) {
    this.writeSocket = writeSocket;
    System.out.println("This is printed on the client terminal");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        OutputStream outStream = writeSocket.getOutputStream();
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            boolean done = false;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);
            while(!done && in.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.print("Server>");
                String line = in.nextLine();
                out.println(line);
                if(line.trim().equals("BYE")) done = true;
            }
         }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown here");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

Two Problems -

1. The string in the Write constructor is getting printed on the client terminal. Why is this happening?
2. Why is the exception being thrown in the Write run() method?

Comment: "The string in the Write constructor is getting printed on the client terminal." and System.out.println("This is printed on the client terminal"); Am I missing something ?

Comment: "Why is the exception being thrown in the Write run() method?". What exception ?

Comment: Why are you immediately closing your Sockets right after opening them? What worth are they to you when you do this?

Comment: When i run the client code the System.out.println("This is printed on the client terminal") gets printed on the client terminal.

Comment: Thanks problem solved

Comment: What problem was solved and how?

Comment: Sorry for not replying, the problem was trivial. The two problems were - I had a very bad understanding of threads and I was closing the sockets on creating them and I was using same class names in the same package causing the string to printed on the terminal running the client code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use two different threads to read and write from the same socket without any synchronization in java?

You can't avoid synchronization because the implementation for Socket is already synchronized.

You can avoid *additional* synchronization if you only have one thread reading and another thread writing.

> The string in the Write constructor is getting printed on the client terminal. Why is this happening?

Most likely because you are running that code on the client as well.

> Why is the exception being thrown in the Write run() method?

You have an error, which would be easier to diagnose if you read it and told us what it was (including the stack trace)

Note:  Threads take time to start and run. If you close the connection immediately, the threads might not even get a chance to read the connection before you have closed it.

```
    read.start();
    write.start();
    incomming.close(); // == kill the connection
```

Instead of using

```
 while(!done ...) {

    if (condition)
        done = true;
 }
```

You can use

```
 while(...) {

    if (condition)
       break;
 }
```